How to properly record and send audio data from react to backend
I want to send audio data from react in a interval of approx. 10sec to my flask backend. Here is my code, it is working but music format is not write.
React Code:
useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();

    function sendData(data) {
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append("file", data, "data.mp3");
      form.append("title", "data.mp3");

      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/save-record", form, { headers })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }

    const audioHandler = () => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then((stream) => {
          const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          var audioChunks = [];

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
            audioChunks.push(event.data);
          });

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener("start", () => {
            console.log("MediaRecorder started");
          });

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
            console.log("MediaRecorder stopped");
          });

          mediaRecorder.start();

          const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (mediaRecorder.state === "recording") {
              mediaRecorder.stop();

              if (audioChunks.length > 0) {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/mpeg-3" });
                // const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                // console.log(audioURL);
                audioChunks = [];
  
                // socket.emit("audioIn", { data: audioBlob });
                // console.log(audioBlob);
                sendData(audioBlob);
              }
            }else{
              mediaRecorder.start();
            }

            
          }, 10000);

          return () => {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            clearInterval(intervalId);
          };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Err capturing audio.", err);
        });
    };

    socket.on("connect", audioHandler);

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      socket.off("connect", audioHandler);
    };
  }, []);

Flask Code:
@app.route('/save-record', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def save_record():
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit an empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".mp3"
    full_file_name = os.path.join("Data", file_name)
    try:
        file.save(full_file_name)
    except:
        print("error")

    return "success"

I am trying to save the audio data on disk. It is suppose to be 10 sec long, but this file dose not have any ending. audio image
Can somebody share how to do this properly? If possible implement using websockets.
Thanks in advance

There are some problems here that I can see that are a likely cause. 1) "audioChunks" is not cleared down (emptied) at the start of each chunk, and so every upload gets progressively bigger. 2) The audioChunks array is read immediately after the mediaRecorder.stop(); call in the code. This wont work, as the final chunk that is to be flushed won't actually be there yet. You can see this in action by checking the first interval, the chunks is of length 0. You need to move the entire if (audioChunks.length > 0) { block and its contents into the stop event handler.

I have done as u recommended but still same result as before. Audio file dose not have any ending https://i.sstatic.net/82hreUHT.png
Clear chunks before start recording
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("start", () => {             audioChunks = [];           }); 
Put data sending logic inside stop event
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {             if (audioChunks.length > 0) {               const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/mpeg" });               sendData(audioBlob);             }           });
Thanks though
